# Wine--Installing Game From Multiple Discs

Tags: lubuntu, wine, games

I installed Wine on my old HP 32 bit laptop. It's about 10 years old but in great condition for what it is. I'm actually running Lubuntu on it. I've been attempting to install XIII (awesome game from 2003 or so), however it gets stuck when the faux Windows asks me to insert Disc 2. PCmanfm doesn't refresh to show what is on disc 2 (even if I manually refresh) and the faux Windows prompt tells me it can't find the file it needs (data3.cab which IS on disc 2) then, pcmanfm crashes, the faux-Windows prompt vanishes and the computer freezes up. I am able to open a terminal to shutdown, but that's about it.

So, I'm wondering, Is there something I don't know about multiple disc installs?  Should I extract all the disc files (there are 4 discs) to a folder on the computer? I'm really looking forward to playing it. Not that I think it matters to this conversation, but here is the terminal command I used to start the install: prompt$:

```
wine /media/sophie/Installation\ Dis/setup.exe
```

The install starts fine but then crashes.

Comment: The file manager shouldn't really care about what Wine does with the discs, so it appears that this part of the issue may be unrelated to Wine. Could you please try what happens when you change discs normally without an installation running at the same time? Also, which version of XIII are you trying to run? With the unofficial patch to v1.4 it has [platinum rating on the Wine App DB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3776).

Comment: When swapping discs without a Wine install going, I can see what's on the discs just fine. As for the version of XIII, I'm not sure...I have the original discs in the original box that I bought sometime in 2003. I don't see any version info on Disc 1 on the install set...thanks for the help!

Comment: If the installer uses `data*.cab` files you can try the following: 1) copy the entire content of disc 1 to a (preferably newly created) directory on your hard drive, 2) copy all other discs to the *same* directory but don't overwrite existing files, 3) run the installer from this directory. The installer will likely find the additional installation archive files that way and not ask for additional discs or you can press just "OK" when it asks you to change discs and it'll find the files.

Answer (score 0):

Install Wine and Winetricks. Go to the games CD/Dvd dir right click on the installers exe choose open with find and choose Wine. When installing give it time to load each disc it will ask for each disc give it a little time to load for each disc. Just got Madden 2005 work flawless. Its a 3 disc game. One of a few a few reasons I still needed Windows 10 was that game, so I guess I need not boot into windows as much.